# Using dynamic lists in query in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say, for the sake of an example, that I have several columns encoding different types of rates (`"annual rate"`, `"1/2 annual rate"`, etc.). I want to use `query` on my dataframe to find entries where **any** of these rates is above `1`.

First I find the columns that I want to use in my query:

```
cols = [x for ix, x in enumerate(df.columns) if 'rate' in x]
```

where, say, `cols` contains:

```
["annual rate", "1/2 annual rate", "monthly rate"]
```

I then want to do something like:

```
df.query('any of my cols > 1')
```

How can I format this for `query`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`query` performs a full parse of a Python *expression* (with some limits, e.g., you can't use `lambda` expressions or ternary `if`/`else` expressions). This means that any columns that you refer to in your query string **must** be a valid Python identifier (a more formal word for "variable name"). One way to check this is to use the `Name` pattern lurking in the `tokenize` module:

```
In [156]: tokenize.Name
Out[156]: '[a-zA-Z_]\\w*'

In [157]: def isidentifier(x):
   .....:     return re.match(tokenize.Name, x) is not None
   .....:

In [158]: isidentifier('adsf')
Out[158]: True

In [159]: isidentifier('1adsf')
Out[159]: False
```

Now since your column names have spaces, each word separated by spaces will be evaluated as separate identifier so you'll have something like

```
df.query("annual rate > 1")
```

which is invalid Python syntax. Try typing `annual rate` into a Python interpreter and you'll get a `SyntaxError` exception.

Take home message: rename your columns to be valid variable names. You won't be able to do this programmatically (at least, easily) unless your columns follow some kind of structure. In your case you could do

```
In [166]: cols
Out[166]: ['annual rate', '1/2 annual rate', 'monthly rate']

In [167]: list(map(lambda x: '_'.join(x.split()).replace('1/2', 'half'), cols))
Out[167]: ['annual_rate', 'half_annual_rate', 'monthly_rate']
```

Then you can format the query string similar to @acushner's example

```
In [173]: newcols
Out[173]: ['annual_rate', 'half_annual_rate', 'monthly_rate']

In [174]: ' or '.join('%s > 1' % c for c in newcols)
Out[174]: 'annual_rate > 1 or half_annual_rate > 1 or monthly_rate > 1'
```

#### Note: You don't actually *need* to use `query` here:

```
In [180]: df = DataFrame(randn(10, 3), columns=cols)

In [181]: df
Out[181]:
   annual rate  1/2 annual rate  monthly rate
0      -0.6980           0.6322        2.5695
1      -0.1413          -0.3285       -0.9856
2       0.8189           0.7166       -1.4302
3       1.3300          -0.9596       -0.8934
4      -1.7545          -0.9635        2.8515
5      -1.1389           0.1055        0.5423
6       0.2788          -1.3973       -0.9073
7      -1.8570           1.3781        0.0501
8      -0.6842          -0.2012       -0.5083
9      -0.3270          -1.5280        0.2251

[10 rows x 3 columns]

In [182]: df.gt(1).any(1)
Out[182]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool

In [183]: df[df.gt(1).any(1)]
Out[183]:
   annual rate  1/2 annual rate  monthly rate
0      -0.6980           0.6322        2.5695
3       1.3300          -0.9596       -0.8934
4      -1.7545          -0.9635        2.8515
7      -1.8570           1.3781        0.0501

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

As @Jeff noted in the comments you *can* refer to non-identifier column names, albeit in a clunky way:

```
pd.eval('df[df["annual rate"]>0]')
```

I wouldn't recommended writing code like this if you want to save the lives of kittens.

Comment: maybe add that you *can* quote the individual names (only with eval), e.g. ``pd.eval('df[df["annual rate"]>0]')`` works (but a bit klunky)

Answer (score 1):

something like this should do the trick

```
df.query('|'.join('(%s > 1)' % col for col in cols))
```

i'm not sure how to deal with spaces in column names though, so you might have to rename them.

Comment: I get `Invalid syntax "(Annual rate > 1) or (Month rate > 1) or (Weekly > 1) or (Daily rate > 1)"` pointing towards the end of `Annual rate`.

Comment: you want to use `'|'` not `'or'` i think

Comment: also i just edited, not sure how to deal with spaces in columns. try renaming.

Comment: Thanks. I tried renaming without luck:

`my_query = "'annual.rate' > 1 or 'monthly.rate' > 1 or 'weekly.rate' > 1 or 'daily.rate' > 1"` I get `TypeError: data type "annual.rate" not understood"`

Comment: Same if I use `_` instead of `.`

Comment: Same if I use `|` instead of `or`

Comment: @user815423426 What about `df.query('|'.join('("%s" > 1)' % col for col in cols))`?

Comment: @user815423426 Humm, after reading the docs it seems that you need to rename your cols in the original DataFrame and do the query. The problem is that pandas uses a modified python syntax so it will not handles spaces, dots or quotes very well.

Comment: Not to nitpick but there's actually only a single syntax modification, and that's the use of the `@` sign to support local variables. The other differences are semantic (e.g., you can use `or` like `|` for bool numpy arrays, chained comparisons). These actually just parse to their native Python equivalents, because they are ultimately passed to `numexpr` which only accepts valid Python code.